# Is there any way to hide/override real IP while using anonymous or transparent proxy?

Tags: c#, winforms, proxy, anonymous

Is there any way to hide/override real IP while using anonymous or transparent proxy? 
I want to send empty in **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR**. I am using C# Winform. Below is the code snippet.

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        //wc.Headers["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = "0.0.0.0";  --Not working
        wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(ipproxy, port);
        string t = wc.DownloadString("https://www.leaky.org/ip_tester.pl");
```

The goal is to send completely anonymous request. The proxies I am using is not brought from any website, they are collected from random sites. It would be great if someone also mention any good site of working proxies.

Thanks

Comment: You can use SOCKS proxies

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can use ProxySharp to generate/get proxy servers to use for your request.

https://github.com/m-henderson/ProxySharp

After you install the ProxySharp nuget package, you can get a random anonymous proxy to use with your request. Like this:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var proxyServer = Proxy.GetSingleProxy();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyServer);
string t = wc.DownloadString("https://www.leaky.org/ip_tester.pl");
```

It also has different methods for getting, renewing, and popping proxies from the queue that it generates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I built ProxySharp to do exactly what you are trying to do.

ProxySharp has a method that will get you a random anonymous proxy to use with your web request. Check out the repo for more info https://github.com/m-henderson/ProxySharp

Answer (score 0):

The `X-Forwarded-For` header is generally added by the proxy server, not the client.  If you put something there, the proxy server will overwrite or append to it.

Comment: So? `The goal is to send completely anonymous request` how to avoid it? I don't see that part in your answer

Comment: You *cannot* make an anonymous request with an http client.  You can ask a proxy server to make a request for you, and that will protect your privacy from the http server as it will think the proxy server is the client instead of you.  It is up to the individual proxy server whether or not to include your IP in the X-Forwarded-For header, or provide other details about you in other headers it might add to the request to the server.

Comment: Does SOCKS proxies also include real IP in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Comment: @ShahBdr No, It is not WebProxy. It forwards TCP/IP level connections. In theory a SOCKS proxy doesn't know the underlying protocol(HTTP in your case) and you can use that proxy for other protocols like Telnet, SSH etc (BTW: if you use Tor, you'll see that it provides you a Socks proxy on your local host)

Comment: @L.B Thanks for clarification.